# Equivalent irreducible linear rep iff determinant is same

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $\pi$, $\pi'$ irreducible linear reps of $G$. Then $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are equivalent iff $\pi'(s)$ and $\pi(s)$ have the same determinant.

If they are equivalent (after fixing basis and identifying the rep with matrices) there is a matrix $T$ such that
$$ T\pi(s)T^{-1}=\pi'(s)\ \ \forall s\in G.$$
And since the determinant is multiplicative, $\det \pi(s)=\det \pi'(s)$.

But in general having the same determinant does not even imply similarity, let alone simultaneously similar (for lack of better phrasing). If this direction is in the affirmative, then I believe I need to apply Schur's Lemma. Any help would be appreciated.

**My Solution:** take $A_5$. $[G,G]=G$ and it can be shown that for abelian $H$
 $$\hom(G,H)\cong \hom(G/[G,G],H).$$ From this we see that $\det \pi$ is the trivial map regardless of the rep of $A_5$. So it can be shown that there is a rep of dimension greater than 1 and this together with the trivial rep shows that the claim is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that irreducible representations which have the same determinant are equivalent. To see an example where this fails in a maximal possible way, consider a perfect finite group $G$ (i.e. $[G,G]=G$). For instance, any non-abelian simple group is perfect. Then the abelianization of $G$ is trivial, so all 1-dimensional representations of $G$ are trivial. But for a representation $\pi$ of $G$, $\det \pi$ is a one-dimensional representation by multiplicativity of determinants. Thus $\det \pi \equiv 1$ for any representation $\pi$. In particular, all irreducible representations of $G$ have the same determinant.